# Multiple csv not being added to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I hope you can help me with this problem.

I am having issues with adding multiple CSV files in pandas.
I have 12 files of sales data that have the same columns (one for each month: `Sales_January_2019`, `Sales_February_2019`.... and so on until December).

I've tried the following code but seems not working, also the index number should be continuous and not reset after each file. I tried with `reset_index()` but also didn't work.

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\Users\ricar\.spyder-py3\data' # my path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0, header=0)
    li.append(df)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

df.drop(columns = ['x_t', 'perf'], inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: whats the error? What happens when you print df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try correcting your code like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'C:\Users\ricar\.spyder-py3\data' # my path
files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

# Make a list of dataframes
li = [pd.read_csv(file, index_col=0, header=0) for file in files]

# Concatenate dataframes and remove useless columns
df = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
df.drop(columns=["x_t", "perf"], inplace=True)

print(df)
```